# Converting a Segemented Ground Truth to a Contour Image efficiently with Numpy

Tags: numpy, optimization, image-segmentation

Suppose I have a segmented image as a Numpy array, where each entry in the image is a number from 1, ... C, C+1 where C is the number of segmentation classes, and class C+1 is some background class. I want to find an efficient way to convert this to a contour image (a binary image where a contour pixel will have value 1, and the rest will have values 0), so that any pixel who has a neighbor in its 8-neighbourhood (or 4-neighbourhood) will be a contour pixel.

The inefficient way would be something like:

```
def isValidLocation(i, j, image_height, image_width):
    if i<0:
        return False
    if i>image_height-1:
        return False
    if j<0:
        return False
    if j>image_width-1:
        return False
    return True

def get8Neighbourhood(i, j, image_height, image_width):
    nbd = []
    for height_offset in [-1, 0, 1]:
        for width_offset in [-1, 0, 1]:
            if isValidLocation(i+height_offset, j+width_offset, image_height, image_width):
                nbd.append((i+height_offset, j+width_offset))
    return nbd


def getContourImage(seg_image):
    seg_image_height = seg_image.shape[0]
    seg_image_width = seg_image.shape[1]
    contour_image = np.zeros([seg_image_height, seg_image_width], dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(seg_image_height):
        for j in range(seg_image_width):
            nbd = get8Neighbourhood(i, j, seg_image_height, seg_image_width)
            for (m,n) in nbd:
                if seg_image[m][n] != seg_image[i][j]:
                    contour_image[i][j] = 1
                    break
    return contour_image
```

I'm looking for a more efficient "vectorized" way of achieving this, as I need to be able to compute this at run time on batches of 8 images at a time in a deep learning context. Any insights appreciated. Visual Example Below. The first image is the original image overlaid over the ground truth segmentation mask (not the best segmentation admittedly...), the second is the output of my code, which looks good, but is way too slow. Takes me about 10 seconds per image with an intel 9900K cpu.

[image]

[image]

Image Credit from SUN RGBD dataset.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Don't all the pixels inside the top & bottom row and left & right columns by default have 8 neighbours? My point here is that there is good possibility of eliminating `isvalid` function and `get8Neigh....` function.

Comment: Also can you explain what is happening in this for loop `for (m,n) in nbd:`? (my understanding- you are checking if the neighbours have the same pixel value as the center pixel)

Comment: @sai I'm not sure what you mean about the pixels in the top and bottom row "by default" having 8 neighbours. For instance in the top row at (0,0) (top left), the only neighbours are (1,0), (0, 1) and (1,1) since obviously we can't go to the left of (0,0) or on "top" of (0,0). Secondly in the loop yes you are correct we are checking to see if any of the neighbours of a pixel are not equal to that pixel, in which case it is a contour pixel since it has neighbours in two different segmentation connected components.

Comment: @sai I should add that while perhaps my 8neighbour and isValid functions aren't optimal, the real bottleneck here is that I'm checking the neighbours of each pixel in the segmentation image array in a non-vectorized fashion, which is very, very slow. I'm looking for a numpy vectorized -esque way to speed this up similarly to  how the numpy.where function is MUCH faster than a double for loop.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and sorry for my wording earlier. I meant all pixels *other* than the ones in the top most row, bottom most row, left most most column and right most column would have 8 neighbours and their indexs could be mathematically calculated and their validity need not be checked right?

Comment: @sai, that's a good point. I could fix that.

Comment: I understand the for loops limitation. Is it possible to share a sample data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226148/discussion-between-integratethis-and-sai).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @sai's idea I came up with this snippet, which yielded the same result much, much faster than my original code. Runs in 0.039 seconds, which when compared to close to 8-10 seconds for the original I'd say is quite a speed-up!

```
filters = []
for i in [0, 1, 2]:
    for j in [0, 1, 2]:
        filter = np.zeros([3,3], dtype=np.int)
        if i ==1 and j==1:
            pass
        else:
            filter[i][j] = -1
            filter[1][1] = 1
            filters.append(filter)


def getCountourImage2(seg_image):
    convolved_images = []
    for filter in filters:
        convoled_image = ndimage.correlate(seg_image, filter, mode='reflect')
        convolved_images.append(convoled_image)
    convoled_images = np.add.reduce(convolved_images)
    seg_image = np.where(convoled_images != 0, 255, 0)
    return seg_image
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work but it might have some limitations which I cannot be sure of without testing on the actual data, so I'll be relying on your feedback.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some sample data with few rectangular segments spread out
seg = np.ones((100, 100), dtype=np.int8)
seg[3:10, 3:10] = 20
seg[24:50, 40:70] = 30
seg[55:80, 62:79] = 40
seg[40:70, 10:20] = 50

plt.imshow(seg)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now to find the contours, we will convolve the image with a kernel which should give `0` values when convolved within the same segment of the image and `<0` or `>0` values when convolved over image regions with multiple segments.

```py
# kernel for convolving
k = np.array([[1, -1, -1],
              [1, 0, -1],
              [1, 1, -1]])
convolved = ndimage.convolve(seg, k)

# contour pixels
non_zeros = np.argwhere(convolved != 0)
plt.scatter(non_zeros[:, 1], non_zeros[:, 0], c='r', marker='.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see in this sample data the kernel has a small limitation and misses identifying *two* contour pixels caused due to symmetric nature of data (which I think would be a rare case in actual segmentation outputs)

For better understanding, this is the scenario(occurs at top left and bottom right corners of the rectangle) where the kernel convolution fails to identify the contour i.e. misses one pixel

```
[ 1,  1,  1]
[ 1,  1,  1]
[ 1, 20, 20]
```

Comment: Very interesting idea! I am going to experiment with your idea and convolve with 8 different filters and benchmark it (one for each neighbour). Thanks!

Comment: Check out my answer, again thanks for the help.